# Retrieve rows where a value exists within a comma separated list

Tags: mysql

**I like to reverse this query:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status IN ( option,option1,option2 );
```

**in a query like**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status contains ( 'option' );
```

Where field 'status' column contains (by example): 'option,option1'.

**When I use**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status LIKE '%option%' );
```

It also selects the rows with a 'status' column that only contains 'option1'

Is this possible?

example data:

```
id,name,status
1,'test1','option,option1'
2,'test2','option,option2'
3,'test3','option2'
4,'test4','option2,option3'
5,'test5','option'

SELECT * FROM table WHERE status contains ( 'option' );
```

This query should select select record 1,2 and 5.

'status' field type is varchar.

The problem is that the status fields contains data that is almost alike, exept from the added number to option. Off course this is a made up example but the real thing has this kind of parameters.

**Update:**
Finally found it after Gumbo's suggestion.

I first tried Gumbo's lead (added the > 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('option', status) > 0;
```

But it did not work either.

After some fiddeling around I found out that the culprit were the spaces between the options in the status field. These records are imported from another source and came with spaces after the comma:

'option, option1' instead of 'option,option1'

**So I ended up with:**

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('option', TRIM(REPLACE(status,' ',''))) > 0;
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Can you give some example data?

Comment: You should not save data like `option,option1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For comma separated values, you can use the [`FIND_IN_SET` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to search for a value in it:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('option', status);
```

To negate the expression, use [`NOT` or `!`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html#operator_not):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET('option', status);
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but this expect the status field to be a SET (or comparable) type but it is a string and the string may contain multiple values (see added text in original post)

Comment: Yes, I did. But in my case something went wrong again, I will explain what did went wrong in my first post. But for now, your post was crucial for me so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to run the extra logic in your query, if you can you might want to just fix the column data:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `status` = REPLACE(`status`, ', ', ',');
```

Then you can just:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('option', status);
```